# How does shell execute normal program?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

First, let's synchronize some information and glossary:

- OS: Ubuntu 16
- Shell: dash
- normal program:
  In the manual of `sh` and section `Search and Execution`, commands are categorized into three types, one of them is normal program

My confusion comes from the part of description about how normal programs are executed, the excerpt is

> Otherwise, if the command name doesn't match a function or builtin, the command is searched for as a normal program in the file system (as described in the next section).  **(1)When a normal program is executed, the shell runs the program, passing the arguments and the environment to the program.**  **(2)If the program is not a normal executable file (i.e., if it does not begin with the "magic number" whose ASCII representation is "#!", so execve(2) returns ENOEXEC then) the shell will interpret the program in a subshell.**  The child shell will reinitialize itself in this case, so that the effect will be as if a new shell had been invoked to handle the ad-hoc shell script, except that the location of hashed commands located in the parent shell will be remembered by the child.

I stress two sentences with numbering to make them clear.

According to what I have learned before, the shell will always spawn a subshell to execute normal program. However, the (1) statement seems like to say that the current shell directly run the program using `execve` as indicated by (2). Only when the program doesn't contain the shebang line then it will be executed in a subshell.

To practice and experiment, I write two simple shell scripts *test.sh* and *subtest.sh*

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ps -o pid,ppid,args -p $$
./subtest.sh
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ps -o pid,ppid,args -p $$
pstree
```

What I get are:

1. subtest is a subprocess of test
2. pstree shows test.sh---subtest.sh---pstree

Then, remove the shebang from *subtest.sh* and run *test.sh* again:

1. subtest is still a subprocess of test
2. pstree shows test.sh---sh---pstree

So, the different is subtest.sh -> sh only. Next, I move to `strace` clone and execve. The results are pasted below

```sh
execve("./test.sh", ["./test.sh"], [/* 88 vars */]) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f2456b559d0) = 25816
strace: Process 25816 attached
[pid 25816] execve("/bin/ps", ["ps", "-o", "pid,ppid,args", "-p", "25815"], [/* 88 vars */]) = 0
  PID  PPID COMMAND
25815 25813 /bin/sh ./test.sh
[pid 25816] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=25816, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=3} ---
clone(strace: Process 25831 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f2456b559d0) = 25831
[pid 25831] execve("./subtest.sh", ["./subtest.sh"], [/* 88 vars */]) = 0
[pid 25831] clone(strace: Process 25832 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fc6e22bb9d0) = 25832
[pid 25832] execve("/bin/ps", ["ps", "-o", "pid,ppid,args", "-p", "25831"], [/* 88 vars */]) = 0
  PID  PPID COMMAND
25831 25815 /bin/sh ./subtest.sh
[pid 25832] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 25831] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=25832, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=2} ---
[pid 25831] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=25831, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

```sh
execve("./test.sh", ["./test.sh"], [/* 88 vars */]) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f960b2769d0) = 24702
strace: Process 24702 attached
[pid 24702] execve("/bin/ps", ["ps", "-o", "pid,ppid,args", "-p", "24701"], [/* 88 vars */]) = 0
  PID  PPID COMMAND
24701 24699 /bin/sh ./test.sh
[pid 24702] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=24702, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=1, si_stime=3} ---
clone(strace: Process 24703 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f960b2769d0) = 24703
[pid 24703] execve("./subtest.sh", ["./subtest.sh"], [/* 88 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
[pid 24703] execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "./subtest.sh"], [/* 88 vars */]) = 0
[pid 24703] clone(strace: Process 24704 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f493e5bc9d0) = 24704
[pid 24704] execve("/bin/ps", ["ps", "-o", "pid,ppid,args", "-p", "24703"], [/* 88 vars */]) = 0
  PID  PPID COMMAND
24703 24701 /bin/sh ./subtest.sh
[pid 24704] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 24703] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=24704, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=1} ---
[pid 24703] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=24703, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Much of the outputs are the same except that the w/o shebang one invokes two `execve`s (one for *subtest.sh*, then for *sh*). And I think the key to understand how normal program is executed is resided in here.

1. Still, the shell always spawn a subshell, inferred by the `clone` call
2. If there is a shebang specifier, it affects which shell interpreter to be used, otherwise, the interpreter is an identical copy as the parent.

OK. After a lot of words, I think the description in the manual is kind of misleading but I'm not sure. How normal programs are executed? Is it correct about my explanation?

Thanks!

**Update**

Yes, I confine myself to scripts w/ or w/o shebang only.
If a binary is invoked, for example,

```sh
#!/bin/sh

date -u
```

Then the result from `strace` is `clone` and `execve`.

```sh
execve("./test.sh", ["./test.sh"], [/* 88 vars */]) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fe4ab21a9d0) = 1218
strace: Process 1218 attached
[pid  1218] execve("/bin/date", ["date", "-u"], [/* 88 vars */]) = 0
Tue Jun 29 07:31:24 UTC 2021
[pid  1218] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1218, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Maybe, I could wrap up:

1. It always spawn a **subprocess**
2. Whether the subprocess is a subshell or not, depends on

   - If the program is a binary, or a script with shebang specifier, then it's a subprocess
   - If the program is script without shebang specifier, then it's a subshell

Comment: I do not understand - what is your quesiton then? You seem to know a great deal about "How does shell execute normal program" - researched documentation and inspected implementation. I do not see - what is the confusion here? `Maybe, I could wrap up:` don't you want to post this as an answer? Yes, it does. Maybe you are confused - yes, "run a program" means fork+exec, it does not mean just exec. `the excerpt is` where is the excerpt taken from?

Comment: @KamilCuk That's the updated part and it comes from what I have done to explore the question and from what people have answered. If the "conclusion" is correct, then that's good. The excerpt is from `man sh` and check the `Search and Execution` section, in which the statement about how it executes is not clear to me.

Comment: I do not understand that part: `Whether the subprocess is a subshell or not` - the subprocess is like in the middle, the "subshell" execution environment has not been setup yet, it's just a child process that does not matter and is going to call exec().

Comment: @KamilCuk When a child process is forked and can be recognized as executable file, the current intermediate state is not important and it's quickly replaced by the program to exec(). But, if that is not a normal executable file, the intermediate state will be initialized as a subshell, by invoking exec("/bin/sh"). Right?

Comment: `by invoking exec` Well, it does not happen "by invoking exec", there has to be some wok after calling/before `exec`, like setting `$PPID` or `$0`, but overall - right!

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes. I understand that exec() is just a, entrance point or something, and there must be some extra works to initialize the subshell before or after the call. And I do find that the man page is often obscure and clumsy. Sometimes I spent much more time to try to understand but was disappointed at the end. I shall extend my reading list, but thinking that it may cost more time and energy makes me a little frustrated...lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man pages are helpful remainders and a nice read - not always (no... very rarely) exact and specific. You might want to read [POSIX sh Command Search and Execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01).

Maybe in more programming steps:

1. It always spawns a [child process](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_93) - creates a "separate execution environment" - `fork()`.
2. Then it calls `exec(name_of_file)`.
3. (Or if for example kernel does not support shebang, the shell may parse `#!` shebang line by itself and extract executable name from it and `exec` it).
4. If that fails, call `exec(sh, name of file)`.

Answer (score 2):

What I think the quoted passage is trying to say is that

1. The shell tries to pass the file to the kernel as an executable.
2. If that fails, the shell falls back to trying to run the file as a script.

What is completely missing from the exposition, and possibly crucial, is the common case of a native binary.  If the file has a magic signature that the kernel knows how to execute, the first case will succeed; the existence of the `#!` magic signature in particular is just a specific generalized case, and I would assume that finding a native binary (an ELF executable, if your architecture is ELF, etc) is included in, and pretty much the standard case, in item 1.

Comment: I update and increase some details about binary.